# FFmpeg text at random position

Tags: video, random, ffmpeg, position, drawtext

I need to print text at random position (to protect videos).

The following works, but it seems that the random position is updated at miliseconds what makes the text go crazy across the screen. Someone has any idea? Thanks

```
ffmpeg -i video.mov -vf "drawtext=fontfile=/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf: text='Test Text':x=random(1)*w: y=random(1) * h" -acodec copy output.avi
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ffmpeg -i dem.mp4 -vf  "drawtext=fontsize=60:fontcolor=white: fontfile=FreeSerif.ttf:text='hello world':x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h-line_h)/2" output.mp4
```

it worked for me.

in the centre of video .

http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Examples-33